# Thread Pool para multiplicação de matrizes em java

Tags: java, matriz, multithreading

Em resumo: Como posso dividir as operações de matrizes e fazer uma pool de threads com uma quantidade fixa de threads utilizando a quantidade de núcleos do usuário? Eu to quebrando a cabeça, procurando no SOF gringo, mas nada que clareie minha mente. Adicionei as bibliotecas `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` e `java.util.concurrent.Executors`. Isso foi o que fiz até agora. Classe principal:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {

         MatrixesManipulations matrixes = new MatrixesManipulations();


         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("De o valor para dimensão das duas matrizes quadradas: ");

         int n = in.nextInt();


         int[][] matrix1 = matrixes.matrixConstructor(n);
         int[][] matrix2 = matrixes.matrixConstructor(n);

         //Processadores do usuario para fazer a pool
         int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

         //Ainda não utilizado
         ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);



         Thread matrix3 = new Thread(new MatrixMultiplicationThread(matrix1, matrix2, n));

         matrix3.start();
         matrix3.join();

         ////Outputs das matrizes

         matrixes.printConsole(matrix1, n, 1);

         matrixes.printConsole(matrix2, n, 2);



         matrixes.matrixesToFile(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, n);
    }
```

Classe `MatrixManipulations`:

```java
public class MatrixesManipulations{

    public int[][] matrixConstructor(int n)
    {
        int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];

         Random rand = new Random();

         for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) 
         {     
            for (int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++) 
            {
                Integer r = rand.nextInt()% 1000; 
                matrix[i][j] = Math.abs(r);
            }
         }
         return matrix;
    }

    public void printConsole(int[][] matrix, int n, int x)
    {
    synchronized (this)
        {
            if(x == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("A primeira matriz gerada de tamanho " + n + " foi:");
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print("[");   
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                       System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("]");
                }
                System.out.println();

            }
            if(x == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("A segunda matriz gerada de tamanho " + n + " foi:");
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print("[");   
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                       System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("]");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
            if(x == 3)
            {
                System.out.println("A matriz resultante gerada da multiplicação das 2 matrizes quadradas foi:");
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print("[");   
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                       System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("]");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

```java
    public void matrixesToFile(int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2, int[][] matrix3, int n) throws IOException
    {
    synchronized(this)
    {
        FileWriter arqMatrix = new FileWriter("Matrizes.txt");
        PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arqMatrix);

        gravarArq.println("Primeira matriz gerada:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {  
            gravarArq.print("[");   
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                gravarArq.print(matrix1[i][j] + " ");
            }
            gravarArq.print("]\n");
        }
        gravarArq.println();

        gravarArq.println("Segunda matriz gerada:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {  
            gravarArq.print("[");   
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                gravarArq.print(matrix2[i][j] + " ");
            }
            gravarArq.print("]\n");
        }
        gravarArq.println();

        //int[][] matrix3 = matrixMultiplication(matrix1, matrix2, n);

        gravarArq.println("Matriz resultante da multiplicação:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {  
            gravarArq.print("[");   
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                gravarArq.print(matrix3[i][j] + " ");
            }
            gravarArq.print("]\n");
        }

        gravarArq.println();

        arqMatrix.close();
        System.out.println("Foi gerado um arquivo 'Matrizes.txt' no mesmo local do projeto.\n");
        }
    }

    public int[][] matrixMultiplication(int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2, int n)
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            int[][] matrix3 = new int[n][n];

            for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
                {
                    for(int k = 0 ; k < n ; k++)
                    {
                        matrix3[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            return matrix3;
        }
    }
}
```

E por final, a thread:

```java
public class MatrixMultiplicationThread implements Runnable {

    MatrixesManipulations matrixThread = new MatrixesManipulations();
    int[][] matrix1;
    int[][] matrix2;
    int n;

    public MatrixMultiplicationThread(int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2, int n)
    {
        this.matrix1 = matrix1;
        this.matrix2 = matrix2;
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int[][] matrix3 = matrixThread.matrixMultiplication(matrix1, matrix2, n);
        matrixThread.printConsole(matrix3, n, 3);
    }
}
```

A intenção é que a thread, a principio, faça a operação da matriz. Mas além disso, quero que ela se divida pra cada thread ir gerando a linha do usuário das saídas. Ou pelo menos (que acredito que seja mais fácil) que elas se dividam e façam operação de soma e multiplicação, não precisa nem ser necessariamente a pool. Outro problema que estou tendo (que possivelmente vou fazer também é gerar uma thread) é pra gerar o arquivo. Tendo em vista que a thread não dá um "retorno" e sim gera a matriz, gostaria de saber uma forma de passar no método `public void matrixesToFile(int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2, int[][] matrix3, int n) throws IOException` na `main` (que é quando eu utilizo esse método pra unificar todas as saídas e gravar num `.txt`.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, pois a sua explicação está um tanto confusa. O que você quer é executar o algoritmo tradicional de multiplicação de matrizes em paralelo e no final salvar tanto as matrizes originais quanto a resultante num arquivo. É isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo! Perdão se me enrolei um pouco, é que to tão estressado porque to há uma semana tentando ver algo e não chego a lugar nenhum haha

Answer (score 1):

Tenta isso:

```java
package com.example.matrixmult;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * @author Victor Williams Stafusa da Silva
 */
public final class Matrix {
    private final int linhas;
    private final int colunas;
    private final double[] valores;

    public Matrix(int linhas, int colunas) {
        if (linhas <= 0 || colunas <= 0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        this.linhas = linhas;
        this.colunas = colunas;
        this.valores = new double[linhas * colunas];
    }

    public int getLinhas() {
        return linhas;
    }

    public int getColunas() {
        return colunas;
    }

    public double get(int linha, int coluna) {
        if (linha < 0 || linha >= linhas || coluna < 0 || coluna >= colunas) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        return valores[coluna * linhas + linha];
    }

    public void set(int linha, int coluna, double valor) {
        if (linha < 0 || linha >= linhas || coluna < 0 || coluna >= colunas) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        valores[coluna * linhas + linha] = valor;
    }

    public Matrix multiply(Matrix outra) {
        if (outra == null || colunas != outra.linhas) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("As matrizes não têm tamanhos compatíveis para serem multiplicadas.");
        }
        var nova = new Matrix(linhas, outra.colunas);
        for (var linha = 0; linha < linhas; linha++) {
            for (var coluna = 0; coluna < outra.colunas; coluna++) {
                var soma = 0.0;
                for (var c = 0; c < colunas; c++) {
                    soma += get(linha, c) * outra.get(c, coluna);
                }
                nova.set(linha, coluna, soma);
            }
        }
        return nova;
    }

    public Matrix multiply(Matrix outra, int threads) throws InterruptedException {
        if (threads <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Deve ser executado com pelo menos uma thread.");
        if (outra == null || colunas != outra.linhas) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("As matrizes não têm tamanhos compatíveis para serem multiplicadas.");
        }
        var pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
        var nova = new Matrix(linhas, outra.colunas);
        for (var linha = 0; linha < linhas; linha++) {
            for (var coluna = 0; coluna < outra.colunas; coluna++) {
                var a = linha;
                var b = coluna;
                pool.submit(() -> {
                    var soma = 0.0;
                    for (int c = 0; c < colunas; c++) {
                        soma += get(a, c) * outra.get(c, b);
                    }
                    nova.set(a, b, soma);
                });
            }
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        while (!pool.isTerminated()) {
            pool.awaitTermination(999999, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        }
        return nova;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(linhas * colunas * 20);
        for (var linha = 0; linha < linhas; linha++) {
            for (var coluna = 0; coluna < colunas; coluna++) {
                sb.append(coluna == 0 ? "[" : " ").append(get(linha, coluna));
            }
            sb.append("]");
            if (linha != linhas - 1) sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static Matrix fromString(String in) {
        if (in == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null não pode ser convertido em matriz.");
        var doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();
        var colunas = -1;
        var partes = in.split("\n");
        var linhas = 0;
        for (var parte: partes) {
            var p = parte.trim();
            if (p.endsWith("\r")) p = p.substring(0, p.length() - 1);
            if (p.isEmpty()) continue;
            if (!p.startsWith("[") || !p.endsWith("]")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("A matriz não contém linhas delimitadas por [ e ] e separadas por uma quebra-de-linha.");
            }
            var itens = p.substring(1, p.length() - 1).split(" ");
            int colunasAqui = 0;
            for (String item : itens) {
                if (item.isEmpty()) continue;
                try {
                    doubles.add(Double.parseDouble(item));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("A matriz contém elementos que não podem ser convertidos para o formato numérico.");
                }
                colunasAqui++;
            }
            linhas++;
            if (colunas == -1) {
                colunas = colunasAqui;
            } else if (colunas != colunasAqui) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("A matriz contém linhas com tamanhos diferentes entre si ou não separadas corretamente.");
            }
        }
        var m = new Matrix(linhas, colunas);
        var it = doubles.iterator();
        for (var i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < colunas; j++) {
                m.set(i, j, it.next());
            }
        }
        return m;
    }

    public static Matrix lerDoArquivo(String arquivo) throws IOException {
        if (arquivo == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return Matrix.fromString(Files.readString(Paths.get(arquivo), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    public void salvarNoArquivo(String arquivo) throws IOException {
        if (arquivo == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        Files.writeString(Paths.get(arquivo), toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    public static void multiplicarEGerarRelatorio(String arquivo1, String arquivo2, String arquivo3) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        var m1 = lerDoArquivo(arquivo1);
        var m2 = lerDoArquivo(arquivo2);
        var m3 = m1.multiply(m2, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        var relatorio = "Primeira matriz:\n" + m1.toString() + "\n\nSegunda matriz:\n" + m2.toString() + "\n\nMultiplicadas:\n" + m3.toString();
        Files.writeString(Paths.get(arquivo3), relatorio, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        var sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Nome do arquivo com a matriz 1: ");
        var arquivo1 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Nome do arquivo com a matriz 2: ");
        var arquivo2 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Nome do arquivo de saída com o relatório: ");
        var arquivo3 = sc.nextLine();
        multiplicarEGerarRelatorio(arquivo1, arquivo2, arquivo3);
    }
}
```

Testei ele com esses dois arquivos:

```
[1 4 5 8 10]
[2 5 8 9 2]
[3 7 4 2 3]
```

```
[1 4]
[2 7]
[3 1]
[3 2]
[5 2]
```

Ao executar ele e informar o nome desses dois arquivos (na ordem) e o nome de um terceiro arquivo que é onde o relatório deveria ser salvo, ele gerou um terceiro arquivo com este conteúdo:

```
Primeira matriz:
[1.0 4.0 5.0 8.0 10.0]
[2.0 5.0 8.0 9.0 2.0]
[3.0 7.0 4.0 2.0 3.0]

Segunda matriz:
[1.0 4.0]
[2.0 7.0]
[3.0 1.0]
[3.0 2.0]
[5.0 2.0]

Multiplicadas:
[98.0 73.0]
[73.0 73.0]
[50.0 75.0]
```

Com exceção do método `fromString(Matrix)`, a maioria do código deve ser um tanto óbvio e autoexplicativo. O método `fromString(Matrix)` é o responsável por ler uma string e montar a uma matriz a partir dela. Essa string tem que ser formada por linhas começando com `[` e terminando com `]` e separadas por `\n`. Os elementos da matriz são separados por espaços. Ele perdoa espaços em branco ou linhas em branco a mais que estejam sobrando.